# SKlearn PolynomialFeatures R^2 score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, polynomials

I'm trying to create a linear regression model with use of PolynomialFeatures. But when I evaluate it, I get really strange scores. I know that R^2 can be applied to this model and I think I've trying everything. I'd really apricate a good advice. Here is my code.

```
X = df_all[['Elevation_gain', 'Distance']] 
y = df_all['Avg_tempo_in_seconds']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

for n in range(2,10,1):
 
    poly_feat = PolynomialFeatures(degree=n, include_bias = True)

    X_poly_train = poly_feat.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_poly_test = poly_feat.transform(X_test)
    

    lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
    lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly_train, y_train)
    test_pred_2 = lin_reg_2.predict(X_poly_test)

    #testset evaluation
    r2 = metrics.r2_score(y_true = y_test, y_pred = test_pred_2)
    mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true = y_test, y_pred = test_pred_2)
    print(round(r2,2))
    #print(round(mse,2))
```

And this is the output I get:

```
0.36
-3.99
-59.96
-1299.38
-627.37
-1773329.36
-19673802.94
-23125681.65
```

Comment: This isn't really a question about programming.  Perhaps you'd have better luck getting a response on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @kosekk_g please provide some sample data to reproduce code.

Comment: @MiguelTrejo

That's how it looks.

'code'
Elevation_gain Distance Avg_tempo_in_seconds
174 13.0 5.71 290.02
173 5.0 6.71 280.03
172 9.0 7.65 292.55
171 9.0 8.08 282.92
170 25.0 10.11 296.34


Thanks!